# Django collect static and requirements

Tags: django

Is there a way to collect static files without installing *all requirements*?

I don't see a point to do `pip install -r requirements.txt` in order to be able to collect static files.

I find this problematic when one wants to collect static files during "build stage" in CI.

Comment: If Django is installed in your virtual environment you don't have to re-install it to "collectstatic"

Comment: I know that, but in case of CI, I would like to keep my Docker image as small as possible and it's absurd that I have to install even pandas just to collect static files

Comment: especially in a CI you want all of your dependencies up to date always. so yes, you need to install them every time.
Otherwise, you can check for changes at the output of `pip freeze` and only then update them.

Comment: I don't want them in my docker image. I found a workaround through "custom" settings.py only for build/CI purposes.